# GCP DNS confusion with Google Domains

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, google-domains

I am on Google Cloud Platform and using Google Domains with Google Mail.
I enabled Google Cloud DNS API, set up Networking - Cloud DNS - Record Sets.

I assume both of the Domain Name Servers should be the same, but when I change the values either from the Google Cloud Platform side or Google Domains, an error occurs.

When I change the Google Domain DNS from ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com to ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com, I receive an error message that states the following:  "It looks like you've changed your name servers. All the settings for your domain (including website, email, synthetic records and resource records) are currently disabled. To enable these settings, you will need to restore the Google Domain Servers."

Does the DNS on the Google Cloud Platform and Google Domain/Mail have to be the same?
Which DNS should go where?

ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com

OR

ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com

Do I need to add any resource records to Google Domains?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud DNS and Google Domains nameservers are not the same, see documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/dns/quickstart#update_your_domain_name_servers

> Even if your domain name is registered with Google Domains, you still need to update the name servers — although they look very similar, the name servers used by Google Domains are not the same as those used by Cloud DNS for your managed zone.

Comment: When I change the Google Domain DNS from ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com to ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com, I receive an error message that states the following: "It looks like you've changed your name servers. All the settings for your domain (including website, email, synthetic records and resource records) are currently disabled. To enable these settings, you will need to restore the Google Domain Servers."

Comment: @Matt: this basically means that you need to maintain all your resource records on Cloud DNS side now. Any settings you had configured in Google Domains will no longer be active, that's why this warning is displayed.

Also, consider to clarify why you want to use Cloud DNS in the first place. Its main benefit in comparison to Google Domains is an ability to dynamically change DNS configuration for massive deployments via API.